# How to add extra data to android.widget.SearchView?

Tags: android, android-searchmanager, android-search

I have defined my `SearchView` like this

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName());

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
}
```

Everything works fine. When I submit query new intent is fired and I capture it in my `MainActivity`. But I do not know where the search query is coming from.

I can see `mAppSearchData` variable that could help me in `android.widget.SearchView`, but it is not accessible for some reason - code `searchView.setAppSearchData(bundle);` does not compile.

Is there some other way to pass pass additional data to detect where the search is coming from?

Comment: I'm using SearchView from the support library: the code "searchView.setAppSearchData(bundle);" compiles and works.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own OnQueryTextListener e.g.:

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MyActivity.IMPORTANT_NUMBER, importantNumber);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, s);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

More Details: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java

It is important that you return true in onQueryTextSubmit, so the searchView does not perform the default action.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the activity name with the query by appending the query. Let's say your query is 'hello', you would append it to something like that 'mainactivity%%hello'. In your search activity, you can then parse the query to retrieve the activity name. Consider this solution has a workaround. There's probably something better out there.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to modify query after submit and before launching search intent. I can only override `onQueryTextSubmit` and implement intent launch myself.